# Not able to get Angular 2 dropdown current value in ngModel

Tags: angular, dropdown

I want to get selected value dropdown based on value of `ngModel`:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <div>
                  <label class="dropdown" for="profile">Profile <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="half">
                  <select class="form-control" name='profile' [(ngModel)]='users.profile._id' required>
                        <option *ngFor="let obj of profiles"  [value]="obj._id">{{obj.profile}}</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `NgModel` directive for dropdown lists, you should always use `NgValue` directive instead of `value` for list items (options):

```
<select class="form-control" name='profile' [(ngModel)]='users.profile._id' required>
    <option *ngFor="let obj of profiles" [ngValue]="obj._id">
        {{obj.profile}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: `value` should still be fine when the values are strings, only when the values are other types `ngValue` is required AFAIK.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was not aware of this. Then OP's problem is that `users.profile._id` doesn't match any of the `obj._id`'s.

Comment: Might be because it's for example a number even when JS usually doesn't mind much about comparing `1` with `'1'`. I'm just sure that it should work with string values.

Comment: Thanks I got answer from you conversation :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer and @Stefan Svrkota

I have intialize `this.users.profile=''` as string previously which was my mistake it should be inialize as object `this.users.profile={}` ,remaining code is working.